# How to filter twice using subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I was trying to select data where the constraints are contradictory. For example there are dataset that contains status_desc as '90 - Lost Opportunity' when the Sproject_Number is not null. I wanted to filter it twice so first i get all Sproject_number as null and then i am able to filter this query again to get a table where the status_desc is '90-Lost Opportunity'

```
SELECT ProjectNumber,
       PName
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           T0.project_number_ext AS ProjectNumber,
           T0.project_key AS PKey,
           T0.sproject_number AS sPNumber,
           T0.project_number AS PNumber,
           T0.schedule_finish AS SFinish,
           T0.status_desc AS SDesc,
           T0.Project_name AS PName
    FROM trimergo.rpt_getProjectPOC T0
    WHERE T0.sproject_number IS NULL
)
GROUP BY ProjectNumber,
         PName;
```

Comment: you need to give the subquery an alias: `WHERE T.sproject_number IS NULL) as T ....`

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem description. Why are you making us guess?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: What's the sub-query's purpose?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question with proper code formatting an error message. Also, when asking SQL questions, it's best to provide sample data as DDL+DML (create table + insert into statements) and desired results.

Comment: Hi sorry, first question on stack, i will be more careful next time. Lamak answered my question, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need this. There is no need for the subquery.

```
SELECT 
        DISTINCT 
         T0.project_number_ext as ProjectNumber
        ,T0.status_desc as SDesc
        ,T0.Project_name as PName
    From trimergo.rpt_getProjectPOC T0
    WHERE T0.sproject_number IS NULL AND 
    ( T1.SDesc LIKE '10 - In Proposal%' OR T1.SDesc like '90-Lost Opportunity%' )
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback. I updated my question please look at the answer i provided below. Thanks

Comment: You do not need a sub query, You can do like above. I have updated the answer for you. You can easily add 2 or more conditions like above. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Pawan, this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This code works, I was trying to select data where the constraints are contradictory. For example there are dataset that contains status_desc as '90 - Lost Opportunity' when the Sproject_Number is not null. I wanted to filter it twice so first i get all null dataset and then i filter that query to close in on the dataset i require

```
SELECT
T1.ProjectNumber , T1.PName, T1.SDesc

FROM
( 

SELECT DISTINCT 
 T0.project_number_ext as ProjectNumber
,T0.project_key as PKey
,T0.sproject_number as sPNumber 
,T0.project_number as PNumber
,T0.schedule_finish as SFinish
,T0.status_desc as SDesc
,T0.Project_name as PName

From trimergo.rpt_getProjectPOC T0

WHERE T0.sproject_number IS NULL ) AS T1

Where T1.SDesc LIKE '10 - In Proposal%'
OR T1.SDesc like '90-Lost Opportunity%'

Group by ProjectNumber, PName, SDesc
```